# Getting the error message

Tags: c++, c, linux

How to get the text of the error message from the stream into a variable?

For example

```
void * thread_func(void ) { 
  char args[]={"firefox","ax",NULL};
  pid_t child_pid = fork();
  if(child_pid!=0) {
    cout<<"error";
  } else {
    execvp("firefox",args); /*something should be done here to get the message*/
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error ? What message ? What stream ? What variable ?

Comment: please post the code that you have to show what you would want were.

Comment: For example void * thread_func(void )
{
char args[]={"firefox","ax",NULL};

pid_t child_pid = fork();

if(child_pid!=0)
{
cout<<"error";
}
else
{
execvp("firefox",args);
/*something should be done here to get the message*/
}

return 0;
}

Comment: edit the code into the question. It is hard to read in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use strerror() to get the string for an errno.  Set errno to 0 before your call, and test it afterwards.  This avoids embarrassing messages like the notorious 'Not a typewriter' from benign calls like printf which can also set errno.

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    errno = 0;
    sqrt(-1.0);
    if (errno != 0) {
        string s = strerror(errno);
        cout << s << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: hard to tell what you're asking, though

Comment: exec and friends set errno on failure, so this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about something like [perror()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/perror/)

Comment: E.g. i'm creating a process in linux, in case it isn't created, there should be a message in the terminal, I need the text of that message.

Comment: perror will print it out, but I think fizzer's got the right idea to store it.